# Impossible to delete row in datable?

Tags: jquery, angular

I am using Angular 9.1.3 and I am trying to develop a screen using datatable. When I load the datatable with data all it Ok. On each line, I have added a button to delete the record. When a click on the button, the record is deleted from datasource (for the moment a test array), it seems to be deleted from the datatable on the screen (it disappears from the screen) but when I move to another page and I come back to the previous page, the deleted records are displayed again. I have tried to reload the datasource as follows :

```
const myTable = $('#myTable').DataTable();
mYtable.reload(this.periods);
```

but that does not work.

I have tried to clear the datatable and to reload the records as follows :

```
const myTable = $('#myTable').DataTable();
const deleteTitle = $localize`:@@deleteTitle:Record deletion`;
const deleteText = $localize`:@@deleteText:Do you want to delete this record with id ${periodId}? :`;
const ret = await this._confirmService.confirm(deleteTitle, deleteText);
if (ret) {
  this.periods.splice(periodId - 1, 1);
  myTable.clear().draw();
  console.log(this.periods);
  myTable.rows.add(this.periods);
}
```

but that does not work also. I have no more idea. If somebidy has one idea to solve my problem, I will be glad. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Where 'this.periods' come from. May be when you go back to the page you are reloading the periods data again in ngOnInit(), ngAfterViewInit(), or in the constructor.

Comment: From the moment the periods come from a static array. I will implements storage in database when this problem will solved.